# Performance at finding all foreigns with 3 one-to-many relation

Tags: mysql-5.5

Basically, I have 2 tables : user and object. One user can be associated to one object by three ways (roles). I want to list all users associated at least to one business object by any role.

This query works, but it takes 5 seconds !

```
SELECT u.id
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN translation_revision t1
    ON u.id = t1.translator_id
LEFT JOIN translation_revision t2
    ON u.id = t2.proofreader_id
LEFT JOIN translation_revision t3
    ON u.id = t3.reviewer_id
wHERE t1.id IS NOT NULL
    OR t2.id IS NOT NULL
    OR t3.id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY u.id
```

Complete fiddle with creation and data here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nojYaUsWicKJDuRQk1Nqd2/7

Any idea on how to improve perf here ?

Comment: also, when remove any one the three left join, the execution time falls at 80ms …

Comment: Left join are costly, but an explain shows that you are already using the indexes, so you will not be any faster and your query doesn't use any where clause.

Comment: Yes, _very_ slooooooooooooooow, at 10 _seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine is fast, at 1-2 milliseconds (tested across various versions between 5.5 and 8.0, plus MariaDB):

```
SELECT u.id
FROM user u
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM translation_revision t1
        WHERE u.id = t1.translator_id )
   OR EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM translation_revision t2
        WHERE u.id = t2.proofreader_id )
   OR EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM translation_revision t3
        WHERE u.id = t3.reviewer_id )
GROUP BY u.id   
LIMIT 30;
```

(I would prefer to use `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`, but probably no performance diff.)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing 3 separate joins, you could accomplish the same thing by simply using an OR clause (the execution time seems to be ~1-2ms):

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id
FROM user u
JOIN translation_revision t1
    ON u.id = t1.translator_id OR u.id = t1.proofreader_id OR u.id = t1.reviewer_id
GROUP BY u.id   
LIMIT 30
```

Other ideas would be to denormalize your data and keep some additional info about your users roles.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I've forgot to change it.

Comment: By the way there is no need in DISTINCT as you already have GROUP BY.

Comment: 2.5-3.5 milliseconds (even with both the `DISTINCT` and the `GROUP BY`).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simply

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id
FROM user u
JOIN translation_revision t 
    ON u.id IN (t.translator_id, t.proofreader_id, t.reviewer_id)
```

?

Comment: 2-3 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You may use union all to avoid sorting

```
mysql> select id from (
->               SELECT u.id
->               FROM user u
->               LEFT JOIN translation_revision t1
->               ON u.id = t1.translator_id  
->union all
->          SELECT u.id
->          FROM user u
->          LEFT JOIN translation_revision t2
->          ON u.id = t2.proofreader_id 
->union all
->         SELECT u.id
->         FROM user u
->         LEFT JOIN translation_revision t3
->         ON u.id = t3.reviewer_id 
-> ) t
->   group by id
-> ;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Reasonable speed at 3-6 milliseconds.